# Use alt + shift + a as a hotkey in IE 7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I am trying to attach an keyup listener on document object. I want to know when user presses <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>. Both work in Chrome and Firefox. In IE, <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> works, but <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> doesn't. I know IE has few hot keys reserved, but why is taking over <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> combination, too? Is there a way to prevent this or is it a flow in IE?

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/HnD5E/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around this behavior with a `keydown` event.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.altKey) {
                 e.preventDefault();
            }
        }).keyup(...);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HnD5E/4/