# Javascript to prevent Alt+Shift default action or to detect multiple OS languages

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I was intending to prompt my users to hold Alt+Shift for a particular aspect of my website. Having written the script, I discovered that in Windows where multiple languages are enabled, this toggles between them, which would not be desirable for the user.

Ideally, I would like to prevent this default toggle whilst on this particular web page or perhaps alternatively check first to see if multiple languages are enabled on windows. As far as I can tell it’s not possible to do either?

The following does not prevent the toggle:

```
e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```

This only detects the languages in the browser, not the OS:

```
navigator.languages ? navigator.languages[0] : (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage)
```

Comment: have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759605/use-alt-shift-a-as-a-hotkey-in-ie-7-8

Comment: You're confusing language (which can be set at the browser level or the user level, and is what you get in `navigator.language`) and keyboard mapping (which is always set at the OS user level). They don't have to be the same, nor even the same as the locale. e.g. I could set my system to match the physical AZERTY keyboard on my Mac, display the UI in English, and dates, currencies and timezone based on wherever I'm travelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key combination is intercepted by Windows, it never reaches the browser, so there's nothing you can do from within a website. The browser doesn't even know about this functionality, so you cannot check for it, either. Choose a different key combination.

Comment: I'm afraid that is correct. Same thing with the default Cmd-Space on Mac OS X which does the same thing (though with Mac OS it's easy to avoid system shortcuts by not using the Cmd modifier in your app)

Comment: Thanks, I suspected so.